# Binding a Dynamic components

Tags: vue.js

I am using Vue in version 2.7 with Composition API and i`m struggling with one thing. I want to dynamicly render a component, based on a reactive value. Here is the code:

```
const renderTab = ref('admin');
// and later in template
<component :is="renderTab"></component>
```

Problem is that i`m getting error:

`Unknown custom element: <admin>`

I am printing the value of  `{{ renderTab }}` and its correct.
Very confusing fact for me is that i can without a problem call this component like this:

`<admin></admin>`
or like this:

`<component :is="'admin'"></component>` or even like this:

`<component is="admin"></component>`

What am i missing or doing wrong guys?

Comment: did you register `admin` in `components`?

Comment: I did in GlobalComponents module from 'vue' :     Admin: typeof import('./src/components/Config/elements/Admin.vue')['default']. If i didn`t i would be able to call <admin></admin> etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A component needs to be resolved before it's used as dynamic component. For globally registered component it can be:

```
const Admin = resolveComponent('Admin')
const renderTab = ref(Admin);
```

For local component it's more straightforward to import and use `Admin` directly.

Comment: I do use: import Administracja from './elements/Administracja.vue';

Comment: Then should be `const renderTab = ref(Administracja )`