# Vue3 Component name not parsed correctly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-composition-api

I have the following `App.vue` that has a dynamic layout setup:

```
<template>
  <component :is="layout" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch } from "vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import DashboardLayout from "./layouts/DashboardLayout.vue";
import AuthLayout from "./layouts/AuthLayout.vue";

const router = useRouter();

const layout = ref();

watch(
  () => router.currentRoute.value,
  (to) => {
    if (to.meta.layout !== undefined) {
      layout.value = to.meta.layout;
    } else {
      layout.value = "DashboardLayout";
    }
  }
);
</script>
```

Now, when running this, I see this in the inspect element:

```
<div id="app" data-v-app="">
<dashboardlayout></dashboardlayout>
</div>
```

Which looks like the component name is not parsed correctly for some reason. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In SFC templates, it can be `DashboardLayout` or `dashboard-layout`.  But in the model it is normalized and made lowercase.  Nothing wrong with this.

Comment: @StevenSpungin ok good to know. The child contents of the layout aren't there though.

Comment: @Bowis See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74463993/3731501 . Should be `layout.value = DashboardLayout`

Comment: Yes, @Bowis dont assign a string, assign the object.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/75857132/2487565 to clarify the problem with passing string instead of components by using SFC with `<script setup>`